# How can I be sure if my tyres are cold for adjusting their pressure?

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

Tyre pressure is to be adjusted when the tyres are cold; as per my car's manual. But how can I be sure that they are cold? The nearest gas station to me is 5 km (3 miles) away.

Comment: You can buy an inexpensive electric pump which you keep in the car, and check the pressures at home. If you have to pay for air at the gas station it will soon pay for itself. They plug into the cig lighter point. I find it best to do with the engine running, so that the power supply is a bit stronger. You can also deal with a slow puncture when you are out and about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Driving such a short distance is unlikely to have a significant effect on tyre temperature/pressure. So driving straight there from "cold" and setting to the manufacturer's recommended pressures is going to be "close enough".

The alternative is to use one of the 12v socket powered air compressors and do it at home before you set off - they're relatively inexpensive these days and can be surprisingly handy to have around. After the first time you need to stop on the hard shoulder of the motorway and top up that slow puncture you didn't realise you had you'll be wondering how you ever lived without one!

Comment: The other alternative is to use a pump.  If I can be bothered, I use my foot pump on my Transit, but for a top-up I just use my floor standing bike pump.  Even the latter is faster than the little cheap 12V  powered ones.

Answer (score 6):

Remember when Mom used to feel your forehead to see if you had a fever? It's as simple as that.

Feel the sidewall of your tire. If it's cold -- which in mechanic-speak means it's the same temperature as the ambient air -- then the tire is "cold" for tire pressure purposes. If it feels warm or hot, then it's not "cold" for tire pressure purposes.